# File specific privacy

Tags: security

How do I encrypt specific files with minimum fuss and bother? I have followed various instructions with more or less the same result; I end up with a folder named 'private'.
I need a folder that I need to password enable.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest method:

```
tar cz {folder} | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e > {folder}.tar.gz.enc
```

After that remove the original folder.

This:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -in {folder}.tar.gz.enc -out {folder}.tar.gz
```

will get you the compressed {folder} without a password back.

---

You can also go with `zip`...

```
zip -e {name}.zip {files}
```

will zip it with a password and ask for it when restoring.